# Fill up missing values with a factor value based on an ID variable

Tags: r, missing-data

I would like to fill the `<NA>` with the correct factor value based on the `ID` variable.

Here are the variables:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Gender_NA <- c("m",NA,"m",NA,"f",NA,"m","m",NA)
Gender  <- c("m","m","m","f","f","f","m","m","m")
```

Here are the data I have:

```
Data_have <- data.frame (ID,Gender_NA)

ID    Gender_NA
 1     m
 1    <NA>
 1     m
 2    <NA>
 2     f
 2    <NA>
 3     m
 3     m
 3    <NA>
```

Here are the data I whant to have:

```
Data_whant <- data.frame (ID,Gender)

ID Gender
1    m
1    m
1    m
2    f
2    f
2    f
3    m
3    m
3    m
```

I have tried to find the solution on this forum but I can´t get i to work.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `na.locf` function from `library(zoo)` can be used for replacing the `NA` elements by the adjacent non-NA previous element.  Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'ID', we replace the NA elements by the previous non-NA, if the first element is NA, it will not be replaced, we can use a second `na.locf` with the option `fromLast=TRUE` to replace the remaining NA with the succeeding non-NA elements.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(Data_have)[, Gender := na.locf(na.locf(Gender_NA, 
            na.rm=FALSE),fromLast=TRUE), by = ID][, Gender_NA := NULL]
Data_have
#    ID Gender
#1:  1      m
#2:  1      m
#3:  1      m
#4:  2      f
#5:  2      f
#6:  2      f
#7:  3      m
#8:  3      m
#9:  3      m
```

Or while grouping by `ID`, we can omit all NAs using `na.omit()` and pick the first element as follows:

```
setDT(Data_have)[, Gender := na.omit(Gender_NA)[1L], by =  ID][, Gender_NA := NULL]
```

---

Or using the same method with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Data_have %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     transmute(Gender= first(na.omit(Gender_NA)))
#    ID Gender
#   (dbl) (fctr)
#1     1      m
#2     1      m
#3     1      m
#4     2      f
#5     2      f
#6     2      f
#7     3      m
#8     3      m
#9     3      m
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dt = data.table(ID, Gender_NA)
# Gender_NA is of character type
```

And here's the answer:

```
dt[is.na(Gender_NA), Gender_NA := na.omit(dt)[.SD, Gender_NA, mult="first", on="ID"]]
```